# Separate SOAP response in android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

Hello Friends I want to make separate value in soap response

```
public class GoldFragment extends Fragment {
int mCurrentPage ;
TextView mTextViewName;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
SoapObject mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse;
public final String NAMESPACE = "http://freewebservicesx.com/";
public final String URL = "http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx";
public final String SOAP_ACTION_1 = "http://freewebservicesx.com/GetCurrentGoldPrice";
public final String METHOD_NAME_1 = "GetCurrentGoldPrice";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    mTextViewName=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    Bundle data = getArguments();

    /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
     mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
     new GetGoldPrice().execute();
    return mView;
}
public class GetGoldPrice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Wait", "Loading");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_1); 
        request.addProperty("UserName","fdsfdsfsdfsd);
        request.addProperty("Password","sfsdfdsd");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_1, envelope);
             mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            Object re= null;
            re = envelope.getResponse();

            Log.i("myApp", mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse.toString());
            System.out.println("response "+mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mProgressDialog!=null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (!mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            mTextViewName.setText(mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse.getAttribute(0).toString());
        }
    }

 }
  }
```

**and my SOAP response is like as below**

```
    01-11 17:39:35.029: I/System.out(25357): GetCurrentGoldPriceResponse{  GetCurrentGoldPriceResult = anyType { string=1,244.73;  string=anyType{}; string=1.33%; }; }
```

so I want to make separate value string=1,244.73 and string=1.33% ,,how can i make it any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution just make a change in two line

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mProgressDialog!=null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (!mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            SoapObject root = (SoapObject) mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse.getProperty(0);
            System.out.println("Price"+root.getProperty(0).toString());
            System.out.println("Change"+root.getProperty(2).toString());


        }
    }
```